# sql query very slow in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, phpmyadmin

I work with mysql and I have a table containing millions of registration, I run a query directly in phpmyadmin, and I wait about 2 minuts to get the result but it shows me `Processing 0.0005 sec`, I do not know where the delay comes from, knowing that I only displays 30 lines per page.
help me please if you have any proposition.

Comment: did you tried explain query and are you table fields properly indexed??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM comments c JOIN users u ON c.user_id = u.id_user_coms
JOIN posts p ON c.post_id=p.id
JOIN pages pa ON p.page_id=pa.id

WHERE c.text LIKE "%iphone%" 
AND pa.name LIKE "%iphone%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Show query please.
Maybe it show you 30 lines per page, but other 1.000.000+ lines always in memory.

Comment: this is my query :

`SELECT * FROM comments c JOIN users u ON c.user_id = u.id_user_coms WHERE c.text like "%iphone%" OR c.post_id IN (SELECT p1.id FROM posts p1 JOIN pages p2 ON p1.page_id = p2.id WHERE p2.name like "%iphone%")`

And my table is :

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comments (
  id bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  text text,
  date varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  user_id bigint(32) NOT NULL,
  post_id bigint(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FULLTEXT KEY 'fulltxt_index' ('text'),
  ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=411078155195366540 ;`